# Question about exercise 17.22 in TeXbook

Tags: math-mode

What is the meaning of the following sentences from the answer to this exercise?

> On the other hand, `\left` will balk if the following character is a left brace. Therefore it’s best to have control sequence names for all delimiters.

This is an example:

```
\tracingmacros=1
\tracingonline=1
$\bigl{\delimiter"426830A}$
\tracingmacros=0
\end
```

As far as I understand, the "`\left` will balk if the following character is a left brace" part refers to the brace from `\bigl{\delimiter"426830A}`. But it makes no sense, since braces are stripped:

```
#1<-\delimiter "426830A
```

The part about "having control sequence names for all delimiters" is therefore confusing, because `{\delimiter...}` works totally fine.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The sentence does not refer to

```
$\bigl{\delimiter"426830A}$
```

which is totally fine because `\bigl` is a macro that takes an argument and will therefore strip braces.  Instead it refers to a (fictitious) construction like this

```
$\left{\delimiter"426830A}\right.$
```

which will not work because `\left` expects a delimiter directly without surrounding braces.

On the other hand this would work

```
$\left\delimiter"426830A\right.$
```

but with this syntax this turns into an error

```
$\bigl\delimiter"426830A$
```

That is why Knuth suggests to define a macro for the delimiters, in this case

```
\def\langle{\delimiter"426830A }
```

because both of the following work flawlessly

```
$\bigl\langle$
$\left\langle\right.$
```